# Wrap the text inside a Button

Tags: java, swt

I am having an issue trying to do what seemed to be an easy task.
Coding an UI in java/swt, I'm trying to get the text of a button display on two lines (wrap the string passed to the button), but I can't manage to do so with the carriage return in the string, nor with the SWT.WRAP style of the button.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
Button myButton = new Button(compoCentre, SWT.WRAP);
myButton.setBounds(40, 200, 240, 40);
myButton.setText("A long text, but not so long, just enough);
```

However, this results in the text displaying on one single line, hiding the part not fitting the size of the button.

Any ideas / workaround ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Works fine on macOS. What platform are you using?

Comment: I'm on a Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out below code :

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        Button testButton = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH | SWT.WRAP);
        testButton.setText("A long text, but not so long, just enough");
        final GridData layoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        layoutData.widthHint = 100;
        testButton.setLayoutData(layoutData);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Output on Windows 10:

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but I don't get why the SWT.WRAP option does not work on his own and we have to go through an "heavy" code jsut to display a wrapping-text button.